# Entityframework code first does not generate database with tabels

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So here I'm following the tutorial from: 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx
to create a database with tabels with code-first approach.

The database should have been generated automatically in my localdb but I cannot find it.

I'm using a visual C# console application in VS2015. Entityframework is installed properly.

```
class SchoolContext: DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base() { }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: add your code here.

Comment: Please add some code, I assume you're not connecting to right database, probably because of connection string in DbContext. That's common issue.

Comment: What code do you need more @Gautam, @MadOX? Is this sufficient?

Comment: you'll need to pass the `connectionstring` to the base `.ctor`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: It's not working. Also I see that my app.config doesn't have a connectionstring tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the connection string in the constructor of the DbContext:

```
     public class Context: DbContext 
     {
         public Context() : base("name=ConnectionStringName") 
         {
         }
     }
```

And then add the connection string to your app.config or web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="ConnectionStringName" 
            connectionString="yourConnectionString" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```